# using xpath to get node value

Tags: r, xpath

I am not sure how to get value under node  using xpath

```
<div class="home_delivery_promo_banner"><span class="fleft"> <strong>Next day delivery (now includes Saturdays)</strong></span>
```

so far I have written below code.

```
 stock =   xpathSApply(page,'//div[@class="home_delivery_promo_banner"]//span[@class="fleft"]//strong//text()',xmlValue,"class") 

parenturl = "http://www.diy.com/nav/rooms/kitchens/handles-hinges/knob_handles/Cooke-and-Lewis-Dimpled-Knob-Pewter-Effect-9291589&bqrefcmp=AW&bqrefcre=AW_AFFILIATES"

srcpage = getURLContent(GET(parenturl)$url,timeout(10))
page = htmlParse(srcpage,useInternalNodes = T,encoding='UTF-8')    
stock =   xpathSApply(page,'//div[@class="home_delivery_promo_banner"]//span[@class="fleft"]//strong// text()',xmlValue,"class")
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Make sure you are using `htmlParse` rather than `xmlParse`. For example, the code below works for me.

```
hp <- htmlParse('<div class="home_delivery_promo_banner"><span class="fleft"> <strong>Next day delivery (now includes Saturdays)</strong></span>')
xpathSApply(hp, '//div[@class="home_delivery_promo_banner"]//span[@class="fleft"]//strong//text()',xmlValue,"class")
# [1] "Next day delivery (now includes Saturdays)"
```

Comment: I am not sure why its not working for me , I have included full code.